Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\harthik.gradle\caches\jars-9\5707c3bbc94e058983781e112864ca77\gradle-1.0.0.jar. >
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\harthik.gradle\caches\jars-9\5707c3bbc94e058983781e112864ca77\gradle-1.0.0.jar. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Stack OverFlow
My Code Was Not Running The APk Is Not Getting The Build

Try this first:

In the terminal, cd into the android directory of the project and run this command
./gradlew clean build

If that doesn't work then:
Run ./gradlew build --scan to get more info about the problem.
If you have to upgrade gradle:
Follow this easy to follow guide: https://tomgregory.com/gradle/how-to-update-gradle/
Or

Find out your java version by running the command:
java --version

Go to
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java
and find out the gradle version compatible with your java version.
mine was 19.0.2 so the matching one is 7.6

Go to your project folder and find the file,
gradle-wrapper.properties in:
android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Change the version number of the distribution Url


for mine:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip

to:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip


Rerun the project, gradle should begin downloading a new version. It
took a while but it worked for me.

